# Log tracing in a Dataflow streaming pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a dataflow setup with multiple pipelines, fetching data from pub sub topics. Since these pipelines fan out and merge with transformers and DoFunctions chains, there is a need to trace each pubsub message coming ingested throughout the pipeline.

What would be the right way to do this? 
Some thoughts:

1. Side Input
2. Each input to a ParDo function to have a context object with tracing ids etc.(A bit unintuitive)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the the tracing? Are you trying to log the id of each pubsub message as it progresses through the pipeline?

Comment: How many messages are you trying to trace (all, some random sample, some specific set of ids)?

Comment: @LukaszCwik Yes I am trying to log the id of each pubsub message as it progresses through the pipeline. As each step there is a transformation and data is enriched from various sources along with multiple validation. And if at any step it fails for some reason I would like to keep a track so that its easy for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your second approach makes the most sense.

Inside your process element function you could catch any exceptions and log any failures:

```
import org.sfl4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ...

public class MyDoFn<ObjectWithPubsubIdA, ObjectWithPubsubIdB> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDoFn.class);

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    ObjectWithPubsubIdA a = c.element();
    try {
      ObjectWithPubsubIdB b = // transform ObjectWithPubsubIdA ...
      c.output(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("MyDoFn failed for message with id {} with exception {}", a.getId(), e);
    }
  }
}
```

You could use an abstract base class or some other language specific construct to re-use the code so you could share one implementation across all your transforms.